# ImageView with rotate xml not rotating

Tags: android, xml

I am using following code,

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/animate"/>
```

My animate.xml is,

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cameras">
```

And in java to start it,

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
              Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.drawable.animate);
              imgView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

But still my ImageView is not rotating,
I have seen many examples, but none of them are working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/animate"/>

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromDegrees="0"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:toDegrees="359"
   android:duration="1000" >
 </rotate>

  ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
          Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.drawable.animate);
          imgView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this in your xml Animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<rotate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="2500"<!-- put any duration you want -->
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="false" >

        <rotate
            android:duration="4000"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"
            android:repeatMode="restart"
            android:toDegrees="360" />

    </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two things that can cause this problem:

1. `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.drawable.animate);` shouldn't the animate.xml be an animation resource in the animation  folder instead of being a drawable?
2. You are rotating from 90 to 90 degrees. Maybe this is just not doing anything.